# How do I use a file grep comparison inside a bash if/else statement?

Tags: bash

When our server comes up we need to check a file to see how the server is configured.

We want to search for the following string inside our /etc/aws/hosts.conf file:

```
MYSQL_ROLE=master
```

Then, we want to test whether that string exists and use an if/else statement to run one of two options depending on whether the string exists or not.

What is the BASH syntax for the if statement?

```
if [ ????? ]; then
  #do one thing
else
  #do another thing
fi
```

Answer (score 225, accepted):

From `grep --help`, but also see [man grep](http://google.com/search?q=man+grep):

> Exit status is 0 if any line was selected, 1 otherwise;
>   if any error occurs and -q was not given, the exit status is 2.

```
if grep --quiet MYSQL_ROLE=master /etc/aws/hosts.conf; then
  echo exists
else
  echo not found
fi
```

You may want to use a more specific regex, such as `^MYSQL_ROLE=master$`, to avoid that string in comments, names that merely start with "master", etc.

This works because the *if* takes a command and runs it, and uses the return value of that command to decide how to proceed, with zero meaning true and non-zero meaning false—the same as how other return codes are interpreted by the shell, and the opposite of a language like C.

Comment: > with zero meaning true and non-zero meaning false—the same as how other return codes are interpreted by the shell, and the opposite of a language like C.

but why the opposite....?

Comment: Because a zero is typically interpreted as "no error", while anything else means "some error". If assumes we want to know if the command completed successfully.

Comment: Gets an upvote (and applause) for using the `--quiet` arg instead of `-q` in the example. Long-args are so much more readable and self document the intention really clearly.

Answer (score 38):

`if` takes a command and checks its return value. `[` is just a command.

```
if grep -q ...
then
  ....
else
  ....
fi
```

Answer (score 27):

Note that, for `PIPE` being any command or sequence of commands, then:

```
if PIPE ; then
  # do one thing if PIPE returned with zero status ($?=0)
else 
  # do another thing if PIPE returned with non-zero status ($?!=0), e.g. error
fi
```

For the record, `[ expr ]` is a shell builtin<sup>†</sup> shorthand for `test expr`.

Since `grep` returns with status 0 in case of a match, and non-zero status in case of no matches, you can use:

```
if grep -lq '^MYSQL_ROLE=master' ; then 
  # do one thing 
else 
  # do another thing
fi
```

Note the use of `-l` which only cares about the file having at least one match (so that `grep` returns as soon as it finds one match, without needlessly continuing to parse the input file.)

<sup>†</sup>*on some platforms `[ expr ]` is not a builtin, but an actual executable `/bin/[` (whose last argument will be `]`), which is why `[ expr ]` should contain blanks around the square brackets, and why it must be followed by [one of the command list separators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html) (`;`, `&&`, `||`, `|`, `&`, newline)*

Comment: `-l` is redundant, `grep` returns immediately upon finding any match with `-q`

Answer (score 4):

just use bash

```
while read -r line
do
  case "$line" in
    *MYSQL_ROLE=master*)
       echo "do your stuff";;
    *) echo "doesn't exist";;      
  esac
done <"/etc/aws/hosts.conf"
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code sample should work:

```
(echo "hello there" | grep -q "AAA") && [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "hi" || echo "bye"
```

Comment: `$?` is not needed here :  `(echo "hello there" | grep -q "AAA") && echo "hi" || echo "bye"`