# Listing non matching entries using 'grep -f'

Tags: parsing, if-statement, grep

The following command gives me a list of matching expressions:

`grep -f /tmp/list Filename* > /tmp/output`

The `list` file is then parsed and used to search `Filename*` for the parsed string. The results are then saved to `output`.

How would I output the parsed string from `list` in the case where there is no match in Filename*?

**Contents of the `list` file could be:**

```
ABC
BLA
ZZZ
HJK
```

**Example Files:**

```
Filename1:5,ABC,123
Filename2:5,ZZZ,342
```

**Result of Running Command:**

```
BLA
HJK
```

Stack overflow question [2480584](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480584) looks like it may be relevant, through the use of an if statement. However I'm not sure how to output the parsed string to the output file. Would require some type of read line?

TIA,

Mic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes it:

```
$ grep -v "$(cat Filename* | cut -d, -f2)" /tmp/list
BLA
HJK
```

#### Explanation

```
$ cat Filename* | cut -d, -f2
ABC
ZZZ
```

And then `grep -v` looks for the inverse matching.

Comment: This worked well. I had a 2nd grep statement that I was able to put into the command and it processes very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, `grep -f list Filename*` gives all matches of patterns from the file `list` in the files specified by `Filename*`, i.e.,

```
Filename1:5,ABC,123
Filename2:5,ZZZ,342
```

in your example.

By adding the `-o` (only print matching expression) and `-h` (do not print filename) flags, we can turn this into:

```
ABC
ZZZ
```

Now you want all patterns from `list` that are not contained in this list, which can be achieved by

```
grep -f list Filename* -o -h | grep -f /dev/stdin -v list
```

where the second `grep` takes it's patterns from the output of the first and by using the `-v` flag gives all the lines of file `list` that do not match those patterns.

Comment: I tried the command but wasn't able to get it to work, probably something I am doing wrong. I had an extra grep statement which searches the files for a 2nd parameter (didn't cover this in the question). I wasn't sure of what /dev/stdin is used for.

Comment: `-f /dev/stdin` is crucial, it makes the second `grep` read its search patterns from standard input (which is the output of the first `grep`).

Comment: If you would edit your OP with the extra grep statement you mentioned, I could edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Though to account for duplicates you should turn that final `-v` into a `-vxF`. You're basically doing a set complement/subtraction: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/set-operations-in-unix-shell/