# How can I check if 'grep' doesn't have any output?

Tags: bash, if-statement, null, grep

I need to check if the recipient username is in file */etc/passwd* which contains all the users in my class, but I have tried a few different combinations of *if* statements and *[grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)* without success. The best I could come up with is below, but I don't think it's working properly.

My logic behind it is that if the *grep* is null, the user is invalid.

```
send_email()
{
  message=
  address=
  attachment=
  validuser=1
  until [ "$validuser" = "0" ]
    do
    echo "Enter the email address: "
    read address
    if [ -z grep $address /etc/passwd ]
      then
    validuser=0
    else
        validuser=1
    fi
    echo -n "Enter the subject of the message: "
    read message
    echo ""
    echo "Enter the file you want to attach: "
    read attachment
    mail -s "$message" "$address"<"$attachment"
    done
    press_enter
}
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Just do a simple if like this:

```
if grep -q $address  /etc/passwd
then 
   echo "OK";
else
   echo "NOT OK";
fi
```

The -q option is used here just to make grep *quiet* (don't output...)

Comment: simplier solution if you don't want to keep result

Comment: How can this be combined with a test of variable value greater than 0? something like `if grep -q $address  /etc/passwd && $val > 0`

Comment: @SumitKumarGhosh -- ```if grep -q "$address" /etc/passwd && [ "${val}" -gt 0 ]; then```

Comment: grep -q not working in solaris..  any idea or alternative?

Comment: I found my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480584/how-do-i-use-a-file-grep-comparison-inside-a-bash-if-else-statement

Answer (score 23):

Use *[getent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getent)* and check for *grep*'s exit code. Avoid using */etc/passwd*. Equivalent in the shell:

```
getent passwd | grep -q valid_user
echo $?
```

Output:

```
0
```

And:

```
getent passwd | grep -q invalid_user
echo $?
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: Why should `/etc/passwd` be avoided?

Answer (score 19):

Your piece of code:

```
if [ -z grep $address /etc/passwd ]
```

You haven't saved the results of `grep $address /etc/passwd` in a variable. Before putting it in the *if* statement and then testing the variable to see if it is empty.

You can try it like this:

```
    check_address=`grep $address /etc/passwd`
    if [ -z "$check_address" ]
      then
    validuser=0
    else
        validuser=1
    fi
```

Answer (score 12):

The -z check is for variable strings, which your grep isn't giving. To give a value from your grep command, enclose it in $():

```
if [ -z $(grep $address /etc/passwd) ]
```

Comment: Could you try adding double quotes?
if [ -z "$(grep $address /etc/passwd)" ]

Edit: Also, shift your entire chunk  of echos and mailing commands into the else clause if you do not want them to be run for an invalid user.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest one will be this:

```
cat test123

# Output: 12345678

cat test123 | grep 123 >/dev/null && echo "grep result exist" || echo "grep result doesn't exist"

# Output: grep result exist

cat test123 | grep 999 >/dev/null && echo "grep result exist" || echo "grep result doesn't exist"

# Output: grep result doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the file I was trying to grep was a binary file. On windows, the first two characters in the file were little squares. On mac, the first two characters were question marks. When I used more or less on the file, I could see it was binary and when I used diff, it responded that the "Binary files foo.log and requirements.txt differ".

I used cat to display the contents of the file, highlighted and copied the text (minus the two question marks at the top, deleted the file, created a new file with touch and then used vi to paste the text back into the new file.

After that, grep worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

```
until ! grep $address /etc/passwd ; do {
    do_your_stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As alienchow said, You can use parantheses with $(). But in some cases, you need to use it in quotes.
For example, in order to check if my kvm is intel or amd, I use this bash code:

```
if [ ! -z "$(lsmod | grep kvm_intel)" ]; then
    echo "kvm_intel found."
elif [ ! -z "$(lsmod | grep kvm_amd)" ]; then
    echo "kvm_amd found."
else
    echo "check your kvm with command 'lsmod | grep kvm' ."
fi
```