# grep and integer expression expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have just lost my mind. I code in Windows, now i have to make one tiny plug-in in Linux, to get communicated with my main code. 
I make code in bash, and on Windows, everything will be ok, but here, on Debian... I have spend 2 days to figure out what is going on, and tried almost everything.

It is my code :

```
#!/bin/bash 
search1=`cat /home/qlik/skrypty/windows/kody.txt | grep -E '[0-2]'`
case $search1 in
[|1|])
echo "Error, need restart"
exit 2
;;
case $search1 in
[|2|])
echo "Warning with server process, waiting"
exit 1
;;
*)
echo "OK"
exit 0
;;
esac
```

I have also tried that way

```
#!/bin/bash
plik1='/home/qlik/skrypty/windows/kody.txt'
szukaj1=$( grep 1 $plik )
szukaj2=$( grep 2 $plik )
if [ $($szukaj1) -eq "1" ] ; then
echo "Error, need restart"
exit 2
elif [ $($szukaj2) -eq "2" ] ; then
echo "Server process warning, waiting"
exit 1
else
echo "OK"
exit 0
fi
```

and all kinds of different ways. All the time I've got an errors :

```
integer expression expected
```

or

```
binary operator expected
```

or

```
[: -eq: unary operator expected
```

I have read about that, i think the problem is with symbols $(...)/[...]/`...`/'...'/[[...]]/$($...)/"..." and I really, really don't know what to do with my code, i tried almost all configurations.

The code is simple -

- it read file.txt
- in file.txt there are 4 numbers [for example : 0 0 2 0 ]
- if all are 0, then is ok,
- if one of them is 1, then is error
- if one of them is 2, then is information that process failed.
- when 1 or 2 are met, the exit code should be the same as error in txt

I just need to recognize what number is in file.txt and show different information and exit code.

Could You please help me?

Comment: What do you see when you launch `echo $search1`?

Comment: when i leave in my script :

search1=`cat /home/qlik/skrypty/windows/kody.txt | grep -E '[0-2]'`
echo $search1

the result is, like my txt file : 
0 0 1 0

Comment: when i leave all as it was, execute the script in main console of linux i get 
* ./qlik_procesresponse.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `$search1'
./qlik_procesresponse.sh: line 8: `case $search1 in' *
and then on that console when I wrote *echo $search1, the result is blank space, like echo of anything = blank enter

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds several problems with the code presented in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

plik1='/home/qlik/skrypty/windows/kody.txt'

if grep -q -- 1 "$plik1" ; then
    echo "Error, need restart"
    exit 2
elif grep -q -- 2 "$plik1" ; then
    echo "Server process warning, waiting"
    exit 1
else
    echo "OK"
    exit 0
fi
```

It's based on the second code example in the question, but the `szukaj` variables have been removed because they aren't necessary (and they were being used incorrectly).

Comment: TY, it works ok. 
So in summary grep could be used next to if, and it does't need any (). 
Why is it so chaotic with that brackets and $ things? 
Could you provide me some sources, where I can learn about that?

Comment: @Renver, see [How do I use a file grep comparison inside a bash if/else statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2480584/4154375) and  [BashPitfalls #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D) for more information about the use of `grep` with `if`.  The use of `$` is confusing because it does three different things: parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.  See [Bash Guide for Beginners - Shell expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) for more information.